# spring boot jar not connecting to Kafka brokers ( setting client_jaas.conf through he system variable java.security.auth.login.config)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot/spring-kafka app which consumes messages correctly when deployed to an external tomcat server as a war file, i set the java.security.auth.login.config environment variable to the client_jaas.conf  file which has the user name and password as below. Now i am trying to deploy the same app to the local Docker container as a jar which uses internal tomcat server, and it looks like it does not connect to the Kafka brokers, from what i understand it does not find the client_jaas.conf  file. Is there a way to have the client_jaas.conf configures in application.properties file or a way to mention username, passwors etc so i can get the authentication to Kafka brokers.

**client_jaas.conf:**

```
KafkaClient {

  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="usse_name"
  password="pwd123";
  };
```

I get this exception below while deploying the jar on a docker or even when i run the jar from the command prompt:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:629)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:167)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:607)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:329)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:340)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:176)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:340)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:312)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:741)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.getServiceName(KerberosLogin.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.configure(KerberosLogin.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:149)
```

I am not sure if i am missing something or if there is a way i should follow to have my client_jaas.conf as a standalone file or have it in app properties file.  I am using the non-secure port to connect to the Kafka brokers

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#kerberos). You can configure JAAS using a `KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer` `@Bean`.

Comment: The `KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer` needs to be declared as a `@Bean`. If that's not it, I can't think of anything else; you'll have to attach a debugger to figure out what's wron.

Comment: I have declared that as a @Bean. I am still getting same error. :(

Comment: I am reading truststore and keystore files in case of accessing kafka on secure port, and while the application was deployed as WAR i used to access them under src/main/resources folder, now that it is a boot jar, how can i access the files now ? what path under the BOOT-INF should i be giving now instead of src/main/resources.

Comment: You should not ask unrelated questions in comments. You cannot access the key stores from a jar - they have to be on the file system; there's an [open JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685).

Comment: Sure, I will ask as a new question with additional question details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue .. turns out on my local, (in an IDE) it just wasn't finding the *.conf files as being visible on the expected path.

option 1: Provide the KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer bean as Gary said.

option 2: Mess with with system properties

```
@Configuration
public class KerberosConfig {
    @Value("${java.security.krb5.conf}")
    private String krb5Conf;  // path to your krb5.conf

    @Value("${java.security.auth.login.config}")
    private String authConfig;  // path to you jaas-client-$profile.conf

    /**
     * This implementation configures the run time environment with the relevant
     * Kerberos security properties.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void setProperty() {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5Conf);
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", authConfig);
    }
}
```